# What is the Android equivalent of JFrame?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just wrote a Java program for a game and I was wondering how I could get the same game to run on Android using Android Studio.

I noticed that Android does not support JFrame, though. What is the Android equivalent to JFrame?

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to understand what the Android Studio version of JFrame would be and how to code it up.  Thanks!

Comment: @KevinBrown I completely disagree with you guys. I mean the question is completely clear: he doesn't have any experience with Android and wants to know what in Android resembles JFrame. How is that not clear?

Comment: @LennartRolland Look at the revision history, at first it was _very broad_ and off-topic (which is why I commented). By the time I came back, it was closed.

Answer (score 4):

In Android what you would usually do is subclass [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) if you want to make a "screen" and [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) if you would like to make a UI widget.

But before you subclass any of them you should know that while they have some similarities to JFrame, they are ***VERY*** different and there are a lot of Android specific stuff you need to know about before you start using them. I would start by taking a  look at [managing activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

For an example of a way to make simple 2D game in Android, [take a look at this](http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/).